# Sphinx searchd: failed to lock .spl file, no such file or directory

Tags: indexing, full-text-search, sphinxsearch, sphinx

I use sphinx for indexing on my development environment, and it is working fine. But when i take it to the server. I can index and I have the indexes with search working on them, but everytime I run the command: searchd --config configfile , it gives me an error:

```
Failed to lock .spl file, no such file or directory. NOT SERVING
Fatal: no valid indexes to serve.
```

I gave permissions to write to that directory, so I am pretty sure it is not a permission issue. I know I am not giving enough info about my case, but in general what could cause a file not to be locked? and is it possible to unlink it manually? or What could it be?

Help please, it's been two weeks of trying to solve it with no success. I am really frustrated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all your index-related files in the folder where your spl file was, including the temp files. Make sure the folder permissions allow writing files to it. Then, restart searchd and reindex. There's no way to fix this without searchd being down/non-functional temporarily, but reindexing is usually fast, so downtime will be minimal.